# How do I get protocol version from System.Web.HttpRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, iis, webforms

I have an Nginx server reverse-proxying my IIS server running af .NET Runtime 4 Web Forms application.

I'm trying to find out what HTTP version (1.0 or 1.1) Nginx is using when making requests to the IIS.

How do I get the HTTP version from the current request?

I've tried searching and looking through the documentation. Closest I've found is the [`ProtocolVersion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.protocolversion(v=vs.110).aspx) of `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` but `HttpRequest` doesn't have the same property and it seems I can't cast it.

*(BTW: I realise that the HTTP version rarely matter these days but it's in relation to some debugging I'm doing)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value is in `Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]` and holds, for example, `"HTTP/1.1"`.

Comment: It's better to use `Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]` because `Request.Params` combines user-provided values from `QueryString` and `Form` (which cannot be trusted!) with `ServerVariables`. In fact, `Request.Params` should be avoided completely.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get and analyse extended information from various websites, the only sustainable solution I could find is to using Selenium, with following peace of could get any information, including protocol version: "H2", "HTTP/1.1" etc.

```
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        //Following Logging preference helps in enabling the performance logs
        options.SetLoggingPreference("performance", LogLevel.All);

        //Creating Chrome driver instance
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(/*your url goes here*/);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);

        //Extracting the performance logs
        var logs = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog("performance");
        string str = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < logs.Count; i++)
        {
            if (logs[i].Message.ToString().IndexOf("\"method\":\"Network.responseReceived\"") > -1 &&
                logs[i].Message.ToString().IndexOf("\"url\":") > -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                     str.Substring(str.IndexOf("\"protocol\":"), 
                     str.IndexOf(",", str.IndexOf("\"protocol\":")) - str.IndexOf("\"protocol\":"))      
                );
            }
        }
```

As you can see from following peace of response, you will be able to get pretty much any kind of information you could possibly need (including protocol version):

> {"message":{"method":"Network.responseReceived","params":{"frameId":"755A984985C3F1263469B348C78A4AA5","loaderId":"2116D4C83A7C6EFD017CC5BC6814FCAB","requestId":"2116D4C83A7C6EFD017CC5BC6814FCAB","response":{"connectionId":41,"connectionReused":false,"encodedDataLength":9595,"fromDiskCache":false,"fromPrefetchCache":false,"fromServiceWorker":false,"headers":{"cache-control":"no-cache,
>   must-revalidate",**"content-encoding":"gzip"**,"content-language":"en","content-type":"text/html; charset=utf-8","date":"Sun, 19 Apr 2020 12:37:09 GMT","expires":"Sun,
>   19 Nov 1978 05:00:00
>   GMT","server":"nginx","status":"200","vary":"Accept-Encoding","x-content-type-options":"nosniff\nnosniff","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-generator":"Drupal
>   7
>   (http://drupal.org)","x-powered-by":"PleskLin"},"mimeType":"text/html",**"protocol":"h2"**,"remoteIPAddress":"195.210.46.29","remotePort":443,"requestHeaders":{":authority":"www.WEBSITENAME.com",":method":"GET",":path":"/",":scheme":"https","accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9","accept-encoding":"gzip,
>   deflate,
>   br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","sec-fetch-dest":"document","sec-fetch-mode":"navigate","sec-fetch-site":"none","sec-fetch-user":"?1","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/81.0.4044.113
>   Safari/537.36"},"securityDetails":{"certificateId":0,"certificateTransparencyCompliance":"compliant","cipher":"AES_128_GCM","issuer":"Let's
>   Encrypt Authority
>   X3","keyExchange":"ECDHE_RSA","keyExchangeGroup":"P-256","protocol":"TLS
>   1.2","signedCertificateTimestampList":[{"hashAlgorithm":"SHA-256","logDescription":"Let's
>   Encrypt 'Oak2020'
>   log","logId":"E712F2B0377E1A62FB8EC90C6184F1EA7B37CB561D11265BF3E0F34BF241546E","origin":"Embedded
>   in
>   certificate","signatureAlgorithm":"ECDSA","signatureData":"30440220600B7A7DE2155D200AE2179CE5E297DC6AB9118E57934440C20E25E33C420ADC02201DC0B323CDCA6BF85100E4816B1405BA5BBB2F41EB225CABCBA4CB5C0513E449","status":"Verified","timestamp":1.586426567863e+12},{"hashAlgorithm":"SHA-256","logDescription":"Google
>   'Argon2020'
>   log","logId":"B21E05CC8BA2CD8A204E8766F92BB98A2520676BDAFA70E7B249532DEF8B905E","origin":"Embedded
>   in
>   certificate","signatureAlgorithm":"ECDSA","signatureData":"3046022100AF260074C39A0F1294C8038BAEE0B85F984C7EC80D10203D6AAAC1BB8B5CDF1D022100ECE351015B9375A3F85CA84EC5CB606A5453AF34AFFDC25C5D32BC938A01FD67","status":"Verified","timestamp":1.586426567862e+12}],"subjectName":"WEBSITENAME.com","validFrom":1586422967,"validTo":1594198967},"securityState":"secure","status":200,"statusText":"","timing":{"connectEnd":399.532,"connectStart":163.118,"dnsEnd":163.118,"dnsStart":163.073,"proxyEnd":-1,"proxyStart":-1,"pushEnd":0,"pushStart":0,"receiveHeadersEnd":2137.345,"requestTime":51622.890236,"sendEnd":399.969,"sendStart":399.759,"sslEnd":399.526,"sslStart":281.492,"workerReady":-1,"workerStart":-1},"url":"https://www.WEBSITENAME.com/"},"timestamp":51625.02969,"type":"Document"}},"webview":"755A984985C3F1263469B348C78A4AA5"}